# how to adjust font size on histogram in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

I created histogram using df.hist() but somehow the font size of my axes is too huge. How do i adjust the size?

[Current plot output with large fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mZyk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the axes label sizes to `df.hist()` like this:

`df.hist(xlabelsize=8, ylabelsize=10)`

See the documentation for pandas.DataFrame.hist() [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html)